# How do I make a page appear like the "Your latest posts" from homepage display options?

Tags: homepage

I want to have what would appear if I chose
"homepage display to: Your latest posts"
but on a page of my choosing and Not as the front page of my site.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get actually what you are asking about but as per i understand, i want to make you clear about setting homepage. I think you are confuse of it.

Basically, homepage setting is the place where you can set your page(home page) to a home page and a page(blog page) to blog page. When you select the homepage setting to Your latest post, instead of showing your front-page.php , home.php or index.php layout is displayed with your latest post.
If you select static and set homepage and blog page, your front page will displayed whatever is in front-page.php and whenever you go to that page, you will see your front page. And for blog page, home.php or index.php is displayed which shows your latest post even after going to page that you set for blog.
 
This is all about the template hierarchy of wordpress. If you want to know more,
[visit] https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a bit of coding to make this work. One option: create a child theme (basically just a `style.css` file with comments in a specific format that let WordPress know it exists), then create a Page Template - a PHP file within your child theme that contains a custom query to display your latest posts like a default homepage would.